Prove the exact result of the following multisum
Prove that
$$
\sum_{n,m = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (-1)^m}{(2n+1)(2m+1)} \frac{\sinh \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{(2n+1)^2 + (2m+1)^2} \right)}{\sinh \left( \pi \sqrt{(2n+1)^2 + (2m+1)^2} \right)} = \frac{\pi^2}{96}
$$
I saw a claim somewhere "the potential at the center of a charge-free cube with one one side held at potential $V_0$ and the other sides at the zero potential, is $V_0 / 6$". When I derived the expression for the potential at the center, distilled down to the numerical factors, this came out. I tried to sum a couple of terms and since the convergence is very fast (due to the exponential factors), so I am pretty confident this is correct.
I also looked into more similar expressions to this one and spotted a certain pattern
$$
\begin{aligned}
S_1 &= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} \frac{\sinh \left( \frac{\pi}{2} (2n+1) \right)}{\sinh \left( \pi (2n+1) \right)} = \frac{\pi}{16} \\
S_2 &= \sum_{n,m = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (-1)^m}{(2n+1)(2m+1)} \frac{\sinh \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{(2n+1)^2 + (2m+1)^2} \right)}{\sinh \left( \pi \sqrt{(2n+1)^2 + (2m+1)^2} \right)} = \frac{\pi^2}{96} \\
S_3 &= \sum_{n,m,l = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (-1)^m (-1)^l}{(2n+1)(2m+1)(2l+1)} \frac{\sinh \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{(2n+1)^2 + (2m+1)^2 + (2l+1)^2} \right)}{\sinh \left( \pi \sqrt{(2n+1)^2 + (2m+1)^2 + (2l+1)^2} \right)} = \frac{\pi^3}{512} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
I think the general pattern is
$$
S_N = \sum_{n_1, \dots, n_N = 0}^\infty \frac{\sinh \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \left( \sum_{j = 1}^N (2n_j+1)^2 \right)^{1/2} \right)}{\sinh \left( \pi \left( \sum_{j = 1}^N (2n_j+1)^2 \right)^{1/2} \right)} \prod \frac{(-1)^n_j}{2n_j+1} = \frac{\pi^N}{(N+1) 2^{2N+1}}
$$
What is this result known as, can someone point me to a wiki page or a paper referencing and/or proving this? What would be the general strategy to prove these results?
